# How to aggregate numbers in a sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this SQL query which searches for parents and children and calculates the weight.

```
select componentid,
         (select sum(cs.weightkg)
            from component c2, componentstats cs
           where c2.componentstatsid = cs.componentstatsid
               start with c2.componentid = c1.componentid
         connect by prior c2.componentid = c2.fkcomponentid) sum_weightkg
from component c1
start with c1.fkcomponentid = 100
connect by prior componentid = fkcomponentid
```

The problem is that I want SQL query to return the total weight as a number (all numbers which it finds to be aggregated).

This is the result that I get:

```
COMPONENTID            SUM_WEIGHTKG           
---------------------- ---------------------- 
201                    410                    
231                    210                    
323                    10
```

Can you help me to rewrite the SQL query?

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/def0e/2

Comment: I don't quite understand.  I see the result you get... but what's the result you want?

Comment: I want to get only the value `410`.

Comment: Can you double check the data in your fiddle?  It doesn't seem to be able to match the result that you want.

Comment: Yes, in fiddle I only want to get the result `7`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(sum_weightkg) from
(select componentid,
             (select sum(cs.weightkg)
                from component c2, componentstats cs
               where c2.componentstatsid = cs.componentstatsid
                   start with c2.componentid = c1.componentid
             connect by prior c2.componentid = c2.fkcomponentid) sum_weightkg
    from component c1
   start with c1.fkcomponentid = 100
   connect by prior componentid = fkcomponentid);
```

I'm not sure that this is the best way but it should work.